# Is this the proper way to do boolean test in SQL?

Tags: sql, boolean-expression

Assume active is a "boolean field" (tiny int, with 0 or 1)

```
-- Find all active users
select * from users where active 

-- Find all inactive users
select * from users where NOT active
```

In words, can the "NOT" operator be applied directly on the boolean field?

Comment: Yes, as was posted, boolean fields are usually typed 'bit', not 'int'

Comment: I assume you are really after nice-looking code, since you would no doubt be aware of that "active = 0" is a possible workaround. In the choice between "NOT active" and "active = 0", I wouldn't bother - if you necessarily need it to be explained, add a comment. (In case someone working with the code in the future doesn't understand the true/false<->1/0 relation, maybe that someone shouldn't touch your code, btw...)

Comment: @Eric: In SQL a predicate needs to produce a Boolean result. A "where active" does not produce such a result, because even if 'active' was a BIT data type - a BIT is not a Boolean value, it's an integer value with a range of 0..1. So you *must* do a comparison of some sort to produce a Boolean. "where NOT (active = 1)" would work, but not "where NOT active".

Comment: Tomalak - you should have posted that comment as an answer!

Comment: @Tomalak: "In SQL a predicate needs to produce a Boolean result" -- not quite. SQL exhibits three value logic i.e. TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN (consider that 'active' can be NULL).

Comment: @onedaywhen: That's right. I always tended to consider FALSE and UNKNOWN as equivalent for all practical purposes. That (and knowing that comparisons to NULL/UNKNOWN will always fail) was sufficient for me so far.

Answer (score 110):

A boolean in SQL is a bit field. This means either 1 or 0. The correct syntax is:

```
select * from users where active = 1 /* All Active Users */
```

or

```
select * from users where active = 0 /* All Inactive Users */
```

Comment: @JoseBasilio- Except in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html

Comment: In most DBs, fields can also be NULL. You may need to check for NULL as well if you don't configure the table with a default value for the active field.

Comment: using SQLite within Rails (4) it made queries using 'f' or 't' (not as chars though). When using the query above it did not work. Though: ```SELECT “model".* FROM “model" WHERE “boolean_column" = ‘f'``` worked

Answer (score 36):

With Postgres, you may use

```
select * from users where active
```

or

```
select * from users where active = 't'
```

If you want to use integer value, you have to consider it as a string.
You can't use integer value.

```
select * from users where active = 1   -- Does not work

select * from users where active = '1' -- Works
```

Comment: looked ALL over to find if it was expecting true or TRUE or 1, so your answer was very helpful

Comment: +1 More on PostgreSQL boolean options: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html

Comment: Aslo, Posgtres accepts OP's syntax: `where active`, `where not active`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-logical.html

Answer (score 16):

MS SQL 2008 can also use the string version of true or false...

```
select * from users where active = 'true'
-- or --
select * from users where active = 'false'
```

Comment: Wow, thats cool... I had no idea that works but definitely does in 2008+ from my testing.

Answer (score 12):

In SQL Server you would generally use. I don't know about other database engines.

```
select * from users where active = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer using char(1) with values 'Y' and 'N' for databases that don't have a native type for boolean. Letters are more user frendly than numbers which assume that those reading it will now that 1 corresponds to true and 0 corresponds to false.

'Y' and 'N' also maps nicely when using (N)Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL supports boolean types, so your SQL query would work perfectly in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -2):

If u r using SQLite3 beware:

It takes only 't' or 'f'. Not 1 or 0. Not TRUE OR FALSE.

Just learned the hard way.

Comment: This is not true. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html: "These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true".